# Apache Camel: how use streaming

Tags: java, apache-camel, streaming

I have a route that needs to read a file from a query(very large, about 100.000) and write it down in another file and then call a PL/SQL procedure.

I used:

```
from("direct:load-R1")
  .setBody(simple("{{sql.r1}"))
  .to("jdbc:r1-datasource?outputType=StreamList&useHeadersAsParameters=true")
  .split(body())
  .streaming()
  .process(new ToFileProcessor())
  .aggregate(constant(true),new StringBodyAggregator())
  .completionPredicate(header(Exchange.SPLIT_COMPLETE).isEqualTo(true))
  .eagerCheckCompletion()
  .completionSize(1000)
  .convertBodyTo(String.class)
  .to("file:U:/Input/?fileName=R1.txt&fileExist=Append")
  .end()
  .to("direct:procedureR1)            
 ;
```

I see that the procedureR1 is called before the transfert in completed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You route does not read from a file it reads from a database and then calls a process in ToFIleProcessor then writes a file. This does not match your description. Is the code above correct?

Comment: You right. My code is correct, my description wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the splitter which has built-in aggregation. See the Camel documentation at: http://camel.apache.org/composed-message-processor.html and see the section *Example using only Splitter*

Comment: Unfortunately, page not found.

Comment: Current link: https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/eips/composed-message-processor.html